# Window.onload Scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var x;
window.onload = function(){
   x=4;
};
console.log(x);
```

The console doesn't output 4, but undefined.

Does anyone know how I would be able to access the changed x variable outside of the window.onload function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because onload hasn't run when you log it, so x hasn't been set yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with javascript's async behavior. The `console.log` doesn't happen after the `window.onload` has fired. They're separate events. If you want it to output the x, you need to do

```
var x;
window.onload = function(){
   x=4;
   console.log(x);
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the x variable outside of the window.onload function?

Comment: You can access the variable x, but it's not guaranteed to be set. If you need x to be set, perform a conditional on it `if x !== undefined`, or if you need to perform a series of actions, run a function from within the `onload()`

Answer (score 3):

window.onload() means after DOM tree are loaded, this function is run. So, `console.log(x)` will be ran before `window.onload()` run

Comment: before that jquery $(function){ ..// code here } will load first, then DOM load and then window.onload().